# Using "gradle-3.5" to build web application but always fail in JPA

Tags: java, jpa, gradle, web-applications

I was tried to build a web application by Gradle and pack a war file.

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'
apply plugin: 'war'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
version = '1.0'
compileJava.options.encoding='UTF-8'
webAppDirName = 'fbs-report'        //set webapp root

sourceSets {
main {
    java {
        srcDir 'src'

        exclude '**/SlablistDload1Controller.java'
        exclude '**/SlablistDload2Controller.java'
        exclude '**/DormantDownloadController.java'
        exclude '**/NewnewController.java'
    }
    resources {
        srcDir 'config'     //prorperties
    }

}
}
repositories {    
 maven { url "http://maven.springframework.org/milestone" }
 maven { url "http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2" }
 maven { url "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/" }
 maven { url "http://amateras.sourceforge.jp/mvn/" }
 maven { url "http://repo.springsource.org/libs-release"}
 mavenCentral()

}

configurations {
compile.exclude group: 'org.freemarker', module: 'freemarker'
compile.exclude group: 'javax.servlet', module: 'servlet-api'
compile.exclude group: 'jboss', module: 'javassist'
}

dependencies {

compile group: 'commons-collections', name: 'commons-collections', version: '3.2'
testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.+'

compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
//spring framework
compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-context', version: '4.3.7.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-test', version: '4.3.7.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-core', version: '4.3.7.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-beans', version: '4.3.7.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-web', version: '4.3.7.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-webmvc', version: '4.3.7.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-jdbc', version: '4.3.7.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-aop', version: '4.3.7.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-tx', version: '4.3.7.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-context-support', version: '4.3.7.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-aspects', version: '4.3.7.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-oxm', version: '4.3.7.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-orm', version: '4.3.7.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-messaging', version: '4.3.7.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-websocket', version: '4.3.7.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-instrument', version: '4.3.7.RELEASE'

//spring data
compile group: 'org.springframework.data', name: 'spring-data-commons', version: '1.12.6.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework.data', name: 'spring-data-jpa', version: '1.11.1.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework.data', name: 'spring-data-rest-webmvc', version: '2.5.6.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework.data', name: 'spring-data-rest-core', version: '2.5.6.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework.data', name: 'spring-data-jdbc-core', version: '1.2.1.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework.data', name: 'spring-cql', version: '1.4.6.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework.data', name: 'spring-data-rest-parent', version: '2.5.6.RELEASE'

//spring-ws
compile group: 'org.springframework.ws', name: 'spring-xml', version: '2.4.0.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework.ws', name: 'spring-ws-security', version: '2.4.0.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework.ws', name: 'spring-ws-test', version: '2.4.0.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework.ws', name: 'spring-ws-support', version: '2.4.0.RELEASE'

//spring-boot
//compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-test', version: '1.4.2.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version: '1.5.2.RELEASE'
//compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter', version: '1.4.2.RELEASE'
//compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-autoconfigure', version: '1.4.2.RELEASE'
//compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-configuration-processor', version: '1.4.2.RELEASE'
//compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-actuator', version: '1.4.2.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot', version: '1.5.2.RELEASE'
//compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-security', version: '1.4.2.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-jpa', version: '1.5.2.RELEASE'
//compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-logging', version: '1.4.2.RELEASE'
//compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-jdbc', version: '1.4.2.RELEASE'
//compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-websocket', version: '1.4.2.RELEASE'
//compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-devtools', version: '1.4.2.RELEASE'
//compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-aop', version: '1.4.2.RELEASE'
//compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-log4j', version: '1.3.8.RELEASE'
//compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-test', version: '1.4.2.RELEASE'
//compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-gradle-plugin', version: '1.4.2.RELEASE'
//compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-deployment-tests', version: '1.4.2.RELEASE'
//compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-parent', version: '1.4.2.RELEASE'

//hibernate
compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-core', version: '5.2.5.Final'
compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-validator', version: '5.3.3.Final'
compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-entitymanager', version: '5.2.5.Final'
compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-ehcache', version: '5.2.5.Final'
compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-c3p0', version: '5.2.5.Final'
compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-jpamodelgen', version: '5.2.5.Final'
compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-search-orm', version: '5.5.5.Final'
compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-tools', version: '5.1.0.Final'
compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-testing', version: '5.2.5.Final'
compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-infinispan', version: '5.2.5.Final'
compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-validator-cdi', version: '5.3.3.Final'
compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-validator-annotation-processor', version: '5.3.3.Final'
compile group: 'org.hibernate.hql', name: 'hibernate-hql-parser', version: '1.3.0.Final'
compile group: 'org.hibernate.hql', name: 'hibernate-hql-testing', version: '1.3.0.Final'
compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-java8', version: '5.2.5.Final'
compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-osgi', version: '5.2.5.Final'
compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-validator-test-utils', version: '5.3.3.Final'
compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-validator-osgi', version: '5.3.3.Final'
compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-gradle-plugin', version: '5.2.5.Final'
compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-validator-parent', version: '5.3.3.Final'
compile group: 'org.hibernate.javax.persistence', name: 'hibernate-jpa-2.1-api', version: '1.0.0.Final'
//compile group: 'javax.persistence', name: 'persistence-api', version: '1.0.2'

compile group: 'org.projectlombok', name: 'lombok', version: '1.16.16'

//apache common
compile group: 'javax.activation', name: 'activation', version: '1.1.1'
compile group: 'org.apache.activemq', name: 'activemq-core', version: '5.7.0'
compile group: 'org.apache.activemq.protobuf', name: 'activemq-protobuf', version: '1.1'
compile group: 'annogen', name: 'annogen', version: '0.1.0'
compile group: 'antlr', name: 'antlr', version: '2.7.7'
compile group: 'aopalliance', name: 'aopalliance', version: '1.0'
compile group: 'org.aspectj', name: 'aspectjrt', version: '1.8.10'
compile group: 'org.aspectj', name: 'aspectjweaver', version: '1.8.10'
compile group: 'org.apache.ws.commons.axiom', name: 'axiom-api', version: '1.2.20'
compile group: 'org.apache.axis2', name: 'axis2', version: '1.4.1'
compile group: 'org.apache.axis2', name: 'axis2-saaj', version: '1.4.1'
compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-pool2', version: '2.4.2'
compile group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi', version: '3.9'
//compile group: 'org.quartz-scheduler', name: 'quartz', version: '2.2.3'
compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-dbcp2', version: '2.1.1'
compile group: 'net.sf.json-lib', name: 'json-lib', version: '2.4', classifier: 'jdk15'
//compile group: 'oro', name: 'oro', version: '2.0.8'
//compile group: 'org.freemarker', name: 'freemarker', version: '2.3.23'
//compile group: 'jboss', name: 'javassist', version: '3.22.0-CR1'
compile group: 'commons-fileupload', name: 'commons-fileupload', version: '1.3.2'
compile group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.5'
compile group: 'org.jfree', name: 'jcommon', version: '1.0.23'
compile group: 'org.jfree', name: 'jfreechart', version: '1.0.19'
compile group: 'net.minidev', name: 'json-smart', version: '1.0.9'
compile group: 'xerces', name: 'xercesImpl', version: '2.11.0'

}
```

When  I execute `$ gradle build`, always fail in task "compilejava"
Here is part of the error mesage:

```
D:\fbs-UAT\fbs-report\src\model\MonitorModel.java:62: error: cannot find symbol
classes={
        ^
  symbol:   method classes()
  location: @interface SqlResultSetMapping
D:\fbs-UAT\fbs-report\src\model\ConvertModel.java:114: error: cannot find symbol
        @OneToMany(cascade= { CascadeType.ALL }, fetch=FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval=true)
                                                                                          ^
  symbol:   method orphanRemoval()
  location: @interface OneToMany
D:\fbs-UAT\fbs-report\src\model\MonitorModel.java:66: error: duplicate element '<any?>' in annotation @<any?>.
                        @ColumnResult(name="sysId", type=Long.class),
                                  ^
D:\fbs-UAT\fbs-report\src\model\MonitorModel.java:66: error: duplicate element '<any?>' in annotation @<any?>.
                        @ColumnResult(name="sysId", type=Long.class),
                                                ^
D:\fbs-UAT\fbs-report\src\model\MonitorModel.java:67: error: duplicate element '<any?>' in annotation @<any?>.
                    @ColumnResult(name="sysCreateUser", type=String.class),
                              ^
D:\fbs-UAT\fbs-report\src\model\MonitorModel.java:67: error: duplicate element '<any?>' in annotation @<any?>.
                    @ColumnResult(name="sysCreateUser", type=String.class),
                                                    ^
D:\fbs-UAT\fbs-report\src\model\MonitorModel.java:68: error: duplicate element '<any?>' in annotation @<any?>.
                    @ColumnResult(name="sysCreateTime", type=Date.class),
                              ^
D:\fbs-UAT\fbs-report\src\model\MonitorModel.java:68: error: duplicate element '<any?>' in annotation @<any?>.
                    @ColumnResult(name="sysCreateTime", type=Date.class),
                                                    ^
D:\fbs-UAT\fbs-report\src\MonitorModel.java:69: error: duplicate element '<any?>' in annotation @<any?>.
                    @ColumnResult(name="sysModifyUser", type=String.class),
                              ^
D:\fbs-UAT\fbs-report\src\model\MonitorModel.java:69: error: duplicate element '<any?>' in annotation @<any?>.
                    @ColumnResult(name="sysModifyUser", type=String.class),
                                                    ^
```

By the way, if takes away codes for JPA, it turns out Successful results.

Comment: Instead of attaching images please add the source code of `build.gradle` and the error message.

Comment: There is currently not enough information. What libraries are you using? Googling for the error message I found for example this bug report: https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/778

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add the dependency on JPA 1.0.2 the compilation will fail since some of your annotations depend on JPA 2.1.

Since `'org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:1.0.0.Final'` already contains the JPA 2.1 API you don't need a separate dependency on `javax.persistence:persistence-api`

Comment: Thanks a lot. After remove "persistence-api.jar", it works well.